# Are the following combinatorics/probability solutions equivalent.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am solving a probability problem in an online textbook. https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter2/2_1_5_socved2_1.php the problem is problem 6. The problem statement is: How many distinct solutions does the following equation have?
$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=100$, such that
$x_1 \in \{1,2,3..\},x_2 \in \{2,3,4,..\},x_3,x_4 \in \{0,1,2,3,...\}$.

The official solution is as follows:

set $y_1 = x_1 - 1$, set $y_2 = x_2 - 2$. sub, $x_1$ and $x_2$. Solve the standard histogram problem using unordered sampling with replacement. The answer becomes $\binom{100}{3}$. This makes sense to me.

However, when I solved this problem I got a different answer. I am not sure how to compare my answer to their answer to check if its correct because my answer has a summation of binomials and im not aware of any way to evaluate it.

My logic:

Consider we have 100 balls. we have a tuple/string with 3 dividers indicating which "bucket" the balls will belong to. If there are 5 balls in bucket 1, this means $x_1$ has a value of 5. Now we know that $x_1$ and $x_2$ buckets must have a min number of 1 and 2 balls respectively.

our tuple/string will look something like this *...|**...|...|.... where ... indicates $0$ or more balls. Let j be the number of balls in the $x_1$ bucket. Typically with histogram problems to find the number of combinations, we find the number of ways we can choose positions for the dividers (the | chars) in our string. This problem is a bit more tricky because there are restrictions on our dividers. Lets say there is some fixed region of characters in our string where we wont let dividers move into that position. With j = 1 the string with the fixed and non fixed regions will look like so (*|**)(|...|...). The first group is the fixed region, the second group is the non fixed region. Clearly we can see we can move the 2 dividers in the non fixed region to any position while maintaining $1$ ball in $x_1$ bucket and $2$ balls in $x_2$ bucket. This string allows the second bucket to include >=2 balls and forces the first bucket to contain exactly 1 ball. Thus the number of ways to form this string/solve the equation would be $\binom{103 - (j + 3)}{2}$. 103 is the total number of characters in the string and j + 3 is the fixed region of the string.

We can have j be any or value from 1 to 98. The max value of j is 98 balls because we need a minimum of 2 balls in $x_2$. Thus the total number of ways to form a valid string/solve the equation would be:
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{98}\binom{103 - (j +3)}{2}$$

I feel like logically my answer makes sense but it seems so different from the official solution I cant help but feel its incorrect.

Comment: Your answer is correct, just in a different expression. The following is true: $\sum_{j=1}^{98}\binom{103-(j+3)}{2}
=
\sum_{k=2}^{99}\binom{k}{2}
=
\binom{100}{3}$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rezha said, the answer is correct just in a different expression.

we can see that

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{98} \binom{103 - (j +3)}{2} = \sum_{k=2}^{99} \binom{k}{2} = \binom{100}{3} $$